# represent tiles in lower dimensionality

Tags: cv.computer-vision

For a naive feature detection algorithm, I'll divide the image in 8x8 grayscale tiles. I want to be able to represent the 64 pixels of each tile in a lower dimensional form. Each tile should be an approximation of a linear combination of less than 64 tiles. What is the name for what I am trying to do? Could you point out some references to this?
I hope this is the appropriate site to ask this question.
Thanks

Comment: By the way, why was this off-topic?

Comment: on second reading, I'm not entirely sure myself. I'm guessing the OP wants some kind of dimensionality reduction method ?

Comment: @Suresh: Why was my close vote removed?  And why cannot I vote to close any longer?  I fail to see any question in theoretical computer science in this post.

Comment: I asked here, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77465/hyperplane-least-square-through-points , Gottfried suggested PCA, I think it will help me. Any related ideas to this? Thanks

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I think there might be some *theoretical* reasons why, e.g., PCA is "better" than ICA or vice versa in this kind of application (for some definition of "better", subject to some assumptions about the inputs).

Comment: I think what happened is that when I reopened, your close vote was wiped out.

Comment: For the record, I am still not convinced that this question is in scope, although I cannot vote to close it because of a bug in the system.

Comment: Replace "8x8" and "64" with "kxk" and "k^2", and it becomes an interesting theoretical question (about dimensionality reduction).  So the question *as written* may not be within scope, but it has small edit distance to a question that is in scope.

Comment: Maybe this question should be closed because it is too vague, not because it is off-topic. Are you trying to a take $64 \times n$ matrix, and approximate it by a matrix of relatively low rank? Is *principal component analysis* the term you're looking for? Or did I totally misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Peter Shor: Yes that is what I want to do, but also find a basis for the columns in the approximated matrix and the coefficients for representing each of those columns in the basis. From what I have read so far PCA finds the basis. By projecting the initial columns on the basis I think I can find the coefficients.

Comment: Projection should indeed find the coefficients.